# Getting JSON.typeMismatch error

Tags: java, android, json

Everytime I run my code I get the following error.

> JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

How can I parse a `JSONObject` wrapped with an array?

Here is my code.

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFeedListener {

     ListView listView;
     FeedAdapter adapter;
     ArrayList<Post> posts;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

         listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
         adapter = new FeedAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_feed_item);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         FeedTask task= new FeedTask(this);
         task.execute("http://www.botswanayouth.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts");
     }

     @Override
     public void onFeed(JSONArray array) {
         posts= new ArrayList<>();
         int length =  array.length();
         for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
             JSONObject object = array.optJSONObject(i);
             Post post = new Post(object.optString("title"),object.optString("excerpt"),object.optString("featured_media"));
             posts.add(post);
         }
         adapter.addAll(posts);
     }

     public class FeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
         private OnFeedListener listener;
         public FeedTask(OnFeedListener listener) {
             this.listener= listener;
         }

         @Override
         protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

             String url = params[0];
             OkHttpClient client= new  OkHttpClient();
             Request.Builder builder= new Request.Builder();

             Request request= builder.url(url).build();

             try {
                 Response response= client.newCall(request).execute();

                 String json= response.body().string();

                 try {
                     JSONObject object= new JSONObject(json);
                     JSONArray array = object.optJSONArray("posts");

                     return array;
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
             super.onPostExecute(array);

             if (null== array)
                 return;

             if (null != listener)
                 listener.onFeed(array);
         }
     }

     public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
         private int resource;

         public FeedAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
             super(context, resource);
             this.resource=resource;
         }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             if (null==convertView) {
                 LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                 convertView=inflater.inflate(resource, null);
             }

             Post post = getItem(position);

             TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
             TextView desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
             title.setText(post.title);
             desc.setText(post.description);

             return convertView;
         }
     }

     public class Post {
         public String title;
         public String description;
         public String thumbnail; //URL

         public Post(String title, String desc, String thumbnail) {
             this.title=title;
             this.description=desc;
             this.thumbnail=thumbnail;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: this is just a piece of unformatted code without any description.

Comment: object.optJSONArray("posts");..???it will be object.getJSONArray("posts");.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your json?

Comment: it is too long though

Comment: will sendd post part of it on the comment box

Comment: array-[

    0object-{
        "id" : number5878,
        "date" : string2016-09-20T14:04:01,
        "guid" : object-{
            "rendered" : stringhttp:\/\/botswanayouth.com\/?p=5877
        },
       
        "type" : stringpost,
        "link" : stringhttp:\/\/botswanayouth.com\/5877\/blow-blow-rappers-beef-dramaboi-vs-emtee\/,
        "title" : object+{ ... },
        "content" : object+{ ... },
        "excerpt" : object-{
            "rendered" : string<p> Sessions next month at Stanbic Bank.<\/p>}]

Comment: Is this the actual format it's returned in? It doesn't match your code at all?

Comment: that is actually the raw data. but i edited it using online json parser

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Inside `doInBackground` or `onFeed`? Also post a sample JSON data. Format your JSON at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your json

```
array-[ 
   0object-{ "id" : number5878, "date" : string2016-09-20T14:04:01, "guid" :         
              object-{ "rendered" : stringhttp:\/\/botswanayouth.com\/?p=5877 }, 
              "type" : stringpost, "link" : stringhttp:\/\/botswanayouth.com\/5877\/blow-blow-rappers-be‌​ef-dramaboi-vs-emtee‌​\/, 
              "title" : object+{ ... }, "content" : object+{ ... }, "excerpt" : 
               object-{ "rendered" : string<p> Sessions next month at Stanbic Bank.<\/p>}
      ]
```

Then in your initial response you are getting a json array not a json object.

So this

```
 String json= response.body().string();

 try {
       JSONObject object= new JSONObject(json);
       ....
 }
```

Should be

```
String json= response.body().string();

try {
      JSONArray object= new JSONArray(json);
      ....
}
```

But it's honestly a little hard to tell because what you've provided doesn't match your code. For example you are looking for a "posts" array in your code, but that's not anywhere in your example json.

Comment: json.JSONException: Value [{"tags":[3131,594,1486,3133,3135,2536,3134,3132,88],"featured_media":3864,"excerpt":{"rendered":"<p>Football pundits and

Comment: org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

Comment: [{"id":5877,"date":"2016-09-20T14:04:01","date_gmt":"2016-09-20T12:04:01","guid":{"rendered":"http:\/\/botswanayouth.com\/?p=5877"},"modified":"2016-09-20T14:21:40",

Comment: In that case I believe the answer I posted should fix your problem. You are trying to create a json object from your string but you have a json array. Making that change should eliminate the error.

Comment: kindly write the code snippet in full so that i clearly understand because i made the corection but the error still persists